# How to control the msn messager's "personal message" displayed to others by python?

Tags: python, msn

How to control the msn messager's "personal message" displayed to others by python?
Want to share some private infomation remotely with this area.

Answer (score 1):

There are many python solutions that allow you to do MSN messaging with Python.

> msnp

This has support for presence states with which you should be able to notify.

- http://msnp.sourceforge.net/

> msnlib

You could build scripts using this library, which is an opensource Python implementation for the MSN messenger protocol version 8.

- http://blitiri.com.ar/p/msnlib/